# Terraform schedule_expression cron errors

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch

This is what I have:

```
  resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "ec2_off" {
  name = "ec2-off-${var.environment}"
  description = "Trigger EC2 schedule lambda"
  schedule_expression = cron(30 18 * * * *)

}
```

This is the error I get with the code above:
│   50:   schedule_expression = cron(30 18 * * * *)
│
│ A comma is required to separate each function argument from the next.

I have also tried this

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "ec2_off" {
  name = "ec2-off-${var.environment}"
  description = "Trigger EC2 schedule lambda"
  schedule_expression = cron"(30 18 * * * *)"

}
```

This is the error I get with the code above:

│ Error: Creating CloudWatch Events Rule failed: ValidationException: Parameter ScheduleExpression is not valid.
│       status code: 400, request id: e91f66b2-db0e-4bfa-89fd-497de9c25107
│
│   with module.ec2_schedule.aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.ec2_off,
│   on ....\modules\ec2_schedule\autoscaling_schedule.tf line 47, in resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "ec2_off":
│   47: resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "ec2_off" {

Please help!

Comment: Add a comma after each function argument inside `cron` function?

Answer (score 3):

The entire thing needs to be a string. Place `cron` inside the quotes:

```
schedule_expression = "cron(30 18 * * * *)"
```

Comment: out of curiosity, can any other function calls besides `cron` be used?

Comment: @d8aninja that's not a function call, it's just an AWS scheduler expression. The two supported expression types are `cron` and `rate`. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/reference-cron-and-rate-expressions.html